# Opencart - phpMyAdmin Bulk update Special Price

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, opencart, price

I work as administrator in one electronic shop we are using OpenCart eCommerce and recently they asked me to add special price to Bulk products and leave it running for some days. Of course i can change it in admin page one by one. The things is how i can change it through phpMyAdmin.
( Opencart Version 2.1.0.1 )

I have 46 products which cost 25€ and i have to add special price to 20€.

Table we have to update price is

```
oc_product_special
```

and column we have to update is

```
oc_product_special.price
```

Of course we need products which cost 25€ from table

```
oc_product
```

to retrieve products from this table and add special price to 20€

The thing is how to connect these two tables so i can add special price which sql query to run so i can achieve this.

```
oc_product & oc_product_special , update this column oc_product_special.price
```

I 've tried to run this sql query but i receive error

```
    UPDATE `oc_product_special`.price
    SET `oc_product_special`.price = 16.1290
    FROM `oc_product`
    INNER JOIN `oc_product_special`
          ON `oc_product`.product_id =`oc_product_special`.product_id
    WHERE`oc_product`.price = 20.1612;
```

**** Price is without taxes 25€ / 1,24(tax rate) = 20.1612€

Error 
**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `oc_product` INNER JOIN `oc_product_special` ON `oc_product`.product_id =' at line 2**

Any help is appreciated
[image]

** **EDIT**

Updating my Sql query

```
UPDATE oc_product_special AS ps 
INNER JOIN oc_product op ON ps.product_id = op.product_id 
set ps.price = 16.1290 
where op.price = 20.1612
```

but the thing is that 0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0003 sec) , if i run select query with these prices i have results.

```
select *
from oc_product as op
where op.price=20.1612
```

Showing rows 0 - 29 (46 total, Query took 0.0010 sec)

***** **Updated 2nd time**

Firstly i ran

```
DELETE FROM `oc_product_special`
WHERE product_id IN
(
    SELECT product_id
    FROM oc_product p
    WHERE p.price = 20.1612
);
```

so i can " remove any existing specials from these products " , this query ran without any issue

After that i tried to ran Insert query

```
INSERT INTO `oc_product_special` (`product_special_id`, `product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `priority`, `price`, `date_start`,`date_end`)
VALUES
(
    SELECT NULL, 78, 1, 0, 16.1290, 0000-00-00, 0000-00-00
    FROM oc_product p
    WHERE p.price = 20.1612
);
```

I adjusted my data concerning to my table's data. But i receive this error

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT NULL, 78, 1, 0, 16.1290, 0000-00-00, 0000-00-00 FROM oc_product p ' at line 4**

Comment: Reading this might help: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: @billynoah post edited, has the right syntax right now but i don't receive any results

Comment: i see you've accepted an answer - does that mean your problem is solved?

Comment: @billynoah  Any help is appreciated Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has no formatting and does not correspond to MySQL standards, you have to pay attention to the following:

- After an `UPDATE` statement one should specify the table to use and not the column
- The `SET` statement only comes after an `INNER JOIN`
- Use suffixes for convenience when joining tables

Correct MySQL query below (change the prices):

```
UPDATE oc_product_special AS ps 
INNER JOIN oc_product op ON ps.product_id = op.product_id 
set ps.price = 22 where op.price = 0.00
```

Comment: thanks for answer i need little more help to resolve this.

Comment: what more help you need? @AgathonMarinopoulos

Comment: Hi Sphinx , as you can see i edited my question following your query but unfortunately i didn't have expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You need an insert statement rather than an update.  You might also consider removing any existing specials from these products beforehand and run a query to clear them like this:

```
DELETE FROM `oc_product_special`
WHERE product_id IN
(
    SELECT product_id
    FROM oc_product p
    WHERE p.price = 20.1612
);
```

Then you can select the desired product ids along with other fields and insert them like this:

```
INSERT INTO `oc_product_special` (`product_special_id`, `product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `priority`, `price`, `date_start`, `date_end`)
VALUES
(
    SELECT NULL, product_id, 1, 0, 16.1290, CURDATE(), CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    FROM oc_product p
    WHERE p.price = 20.1612
);
```

In this example the special starts today and runs for 5 days.  Of course you should adjust the `customer_group_id`, `priority,`start_date`, and`end_date` in my query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i updated my question , because i still receive error in my query trying to add special price in specific products.

Comment: the query you ran is not the same as what i provided.